# Complex lifestyle and leads us to get on the correct path

Tags: theravada, modern-world

Today, we are living in very complex world. Various lifestyles inspire us greatly. So as being a modern layperson, it is difficult to know good karma and bad one. How would I will be on good path and eventually attain Nirvana with 21 century lifestyle? I wouldn't know which activities and deeds have to stop from doing. Which Buddha teachings do I have to follow, differentiating current lifestyles and livings?

Answer (score 3):

Virtue or *sila* at the very minimum is the [five precepts](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sila/pancasila.html). This is the minimum practice of Buddhism.

The five precepts (and other precepts) are undertaken as a training on a "try your best basis". If you lapse, you should try harder next time, without feeling remorse. Striving for perfection in the practice of virtue or *sila* is not required for lay persons.

Further practice of virtue is by the [eight precepts](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sila/atthasila.html) (usually in the context of *[uposatha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uposatha)*), [ten precepts](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sila/dasasila.html) (as a [novice monk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samanera)), [Right Livelihood](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-ajivo/index.html), [Right Speech](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-vaca/index.html) and [Right Action](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-kammanto/index.html).

Right Livelihood for laypersons is explained in [AN 5.177](https://suttacentral.net/an5.177/en/sujato).

Further information can be found in [AccessToInsight's virtue (sila) page](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sila/index.html), including sutta verses.

To practice virtue (sila), the first step is to vow to undertake the training of the [five precepts](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sila/pancasila.html), and then practice them with [heedfulness (appamada)](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/22181/471).

The second step is to adopt this thinking from [AN 5.57](https://suttacentral.net/an5.57/en/bodhi):

> “And for the sake of what benefit should a woman or a man, a
> householder or one gone forth, often reflect thus: ‘I am the owner of
> my kamma, the heir of my kamma; I have kamma as my origin, kamma as my
> relative, kamma as my resort; I will be the heir of whatever kamma,
> good or bad, that I do’? People engage in misconduct by body, speech,
> and mind. **But when one often reflects upon this theme, such misconduct
> is either completely abandoned or diminished**. It is for the sake of
> this benefit that a woman or a man, a householder or one gone forth,
> should often reflect thus: ‘I am the owner of my kamma, the heir of my
> kamma; I have kamma as my origin, kamma as my relative, kamma as my
> resort; I will be the heir of whatever kamma, good or bad, that I do.’

The third step is to understand more deeply from the Dhamma on [Right Livelihood](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-ajivo/index.html), [Right Speech](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-vaca/index.html) and [Right Action](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-kammanto/index.html), and practise them with [heedfulness (*appamada*)](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/22181/471).

Also, please see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/45296/471) for the question "Are the Five Precepts a gradual training?".